# rethinkdb-migrate migration file in location

Tags: rethinkdb, migrate, rethinkdbdash

I am using `rethinkdb-migrate` for migrating rethink db database object.

I am running the following command  -

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --db=test
```

When the migration file is in `migrations` folder it's working as expected.
but when I am moving the migration folder within another folder ( `db` ), it's not working.

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --file /db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js --db=test
```

The above command gives following error -

```
/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1133
      else throw err
           ^

Error: Cannot find module '/db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at readOptionsFile (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/bin/rethinkdb-migrate:140:10)
    at buildOptions (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/bin/rethinkdb-migrate:120:21)
    at runMigrations (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/bin/rethinkdb-migrate:96:19)
    at Object.runCommand (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:235:44)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1046:30)
    at Object.get [as argv] (/home/bappaditya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/rethinkdb-migrate/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:989:21)
```

I triple checked, `20180725062631-scehma.js` exists in db/migrations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have misspelled the name of the file, "-scehma" to "-schema" :

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --file /db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js --db=test
```

It should be:

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --file /db/migrations/20180725062631-schema.js --db=test
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless your `db` folder is in the root, you shouldn't use the leading slash.

So instead of:

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --file /db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js --db=test
```

Use:

```
rethinkdb-migrate up --file db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js --db=test
```

Comment: tried that too, it's giving me an error -
Error: Cannot find module '<path to project root>/db/migrations/20180725062631-scehma.js'

Comment: I did a test with an empty schema file, and if it can find the file at all, it will attempt to connect - even before checking if the file is trash, like mine. I suggest copying the module name from that output and doing an `ls`. Almost certainly, that's not going to show your file.